# extjs XTemplate работа с подмассивом

Tags: extjs

Мой шаблон:

```
new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<tpl for="data">',
                '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="streaks-row">',
                '<tr class="title"><td></td><td colspan="3">{title} <span class="hint">{hint}</span></td></tr>',
                '<tpl for="data.matches">',
                '<tr class="streaks-match-row">',
                '<td><img src="{flag}" alt="" /></td>',
                '<td>{devision}</td>',
                '<td>{team}</td>',
                '<td><div style="width: {percent}%;">{value}</div></td>',
                '</tr>',
                '</tpl>',
                '<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>',
                '</table>',
'</tpl>');
```

Данные:

```
"data":[
       {"id":0,"title":"Win","hint":"","matches":
          {
             "1":{"flag":"g","team":"Teamname","devision":"D1","value":10,"percent":0},
             "2":{"flag":"g","team":"Teamname","devision":"D1","value":1,"percent":0},
             "3":{"flag":"g","team":"Teamname","devision":"D1","value":6,"percent":0},
             "4":{"flag":"g","team":"Team name","devision":"D1","value":5,"percent":0}
          }
       },
      {"id":1,"title":"Draw","hint":"","matches":
         {
            "1":{"flag":"g","team":"Teamname","devision":"D1","value":3,"percent":0},
            "2":{"flag":"g","team":"Teamname","devision":"D1","value":8,"percent":0},
            "3":{"flag":"g","team":"Teamname","devision":"D1","value":10,"percent":0},
            "4":{"flag":"g","team":"Team name","devision":"D1","value":5,"percent":0}
         }
      }
]
```

Данные из массива data нормально отображаются, а из его подмассива matches не отображаются.

Comment: Рекомендую Вам задавая на вопросы по ExtJs указывать его версию)

Comment: Extjs версии 6.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что подмассив matches начинался с 1, а не с 0.